# Promote nuget package to a DevOps feed view via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to figure out a programmatic way to promote my Nuget packages to pre-defined views in Azure DevOps package feed. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifactspackagetypes/nuget/update%20package%20version?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#jsonpatchoperation) link but without any examples. I am using PowerShell and getting this error when I try to invoke the documented PATCH command:

> The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."

This is what I've tried:

```
$pkgUri = "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/$tfsOrganization/$tfsProjectName/_apis/packaging/feeds/$PackageFeedName/nuget/packages/$pkgName/versions/$pkgVersion?api-version=5.1-preview.1"

$json = '{ "views": { "op":"add", "path":"/views/-", "value":"' + 'PreRelease' + '" } }'

$promotePackage = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $allPackagesApiUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Method PATCH -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Body $json
```

Comment: try `-ContentType "application/json-patch+json"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rest API you are using is the right one. For example take a look at below code snippet:

```
function Set-PackageQuality
{
 [CmdletBinding()]
 [OutputType([object])]
 param
 (
 [string] $feedName="",
 [string] $packageId="",
 [string] $packageVersion="",
 [string] $packageQuality=""

 )

$token = New-VSTSAuthenticationToken
 $releaseViewURL = "$basepackageurl/$feedName/nuget/packages/$packageId/
versions/$($packageVersion)?api-version=5.0-preview.1"


}
```

More detail take a look at this blog -- [Programmatically promote your package quality with Release Views in VSTS](https://roadtoalm.com/2017/01/16/programmatically-promote-your-package-quality-with-release-views-in-vsts/)